# amdccc Tear Free option cannot be enabled anymore?

Tags: ati, graphics

After installing the ATI proprietary driver, I disabled the Tear Free option because it causes laggy windows and general slowdown of everything.

But now I want to enable it again, to see whether it improves my video playing (which has lots of screen tearing). The problem is whenever I try to enable the option, it gives me "Tear Free Desktop cannot be enabled due to insufficient graphics memory".

I don't understand, as I could enable and disable it before no problems. I'm running on an ATI 4670.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this in a terminal, if you get any faults please add them to the question:

`sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-u32=DDX,EnableTearFreeDesktop,1`

Comment: It gives:
"sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-u32=DDX,EnableTearFreeDesktop,1"

but in amdccc it's still disabled. Is it done?

Comment: if you got no faults yeah, it should be done.

Comment: maybe run amdccc as sudo will give you extra options?

Comment: did your tear go away?

Comment: I'm not really sure actually. Dragging windows does seem like there is no more tearing though! But playing videos still does...... hmmm :/ well thanks for your help! Good answer. I'll have to bookmark this page just in case.

Comment: For videos you need to disable opengl vblan sync in cscm, or just use ubuntu-2d instead of ubuntu-3d

Comment: Alright. Thanks for all the help! Really appreciate it.